# What is the correct formula for Bayesian update for normal distribution with known variance

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, variance, mean

As question title states, I'm interesting in Bayesian update of normally distributed data with known variance. I compared three sources and they seems to contradict each other. I use some kind of unified notation:

1) [Murphy K. P. (2007)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf)

$$\mu_{post} = \frac{n\times\sigma_{prior}^2}{\sigma_{known}^2+n \times\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \bar x+\frac{\sigma_{known}^2}{\sigma_{known}^2+n\times\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \mu_{prior}$$

$$\sigma_{post}^2=(\frac{1}{\sigma_{prior}^2}+\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2})^{-1}$$

2) [Jordan M. I. (2010)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf)

$$\mu_{post} = \frac{\sigma_{prior}^2}{\frac{\sigma_{known}^2}{n}+\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \bar x+\frac{\sigma_{known}^2}{\frac{\sigma_{known}^2}{n}+\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \mu_{prior}$$

$$\sigma_{post}^2=(\frac{1}{\sigma_{prior}^2}+\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2})^{-1}$$

3) [Gelman A. et. al (2014): 42](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/)

$$\mu_{post} = \frac{\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2}}{\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2}+\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \bar x+\frac{\sigma_{prior}^2}{\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2}+\sigma_{prior}^2}\times \mu_{prior}$$

$$\sigma_{post}^2=(\sigma_{prior}^2+\frac{n}{\sigma_{known}^2})^{-1}$$

I'm asking for two things:

1) verification of my notation changes from original sources

2) if they are correct, explanation of the difference between them

Comment: The most basic difference is that Murply uses normal distribution parametrized by variance $\sigma^2$, while Gelman uses [precission](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183522/antonym-of-variance/183523#183523) $\tau^2$ (you incorrectly used the same symbol in both cases).

Comment: Yes, that correct, Gelman uses precission, but I converted his precission $\tau^2$ to $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$, am I?