# Let $S = X + U, T = X + V$ for ind.normal r.v $X, U,V$. Is it possible to find $a, b$ real numbers such that $\mathbb{E}[X|S,T] = \mathbb{E}[X|aS+bT]$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have random variables
$$X \sim  N(0, \sigma_X^2) \\
U \sim N(0, \sigma_U^2) \\ 
V \sim N(0, \sigma_V^2), $$
where $X$, $U$ and $V$ are independent. And
$$ S = X + U \\ T = X + V. $$

Is it possible to define a linear combination of $S$ and $T$ such that conditioning on
$$R := aS + bT, \ \ \ a, b \in 
 \mathbb{R}$$
is equivalent to conditioning on both $S$ and $T$, i.e.,
$$ \mathbb{E}[X\mid S,T] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid R]. $$

I think knowing $S$ and $T$ is more than just knowing their sum or average.

Comment: I think the answer depends on the full joint distribution of $(X,U,V)$ and not just on their marginal distributions.  Are you perhaps supposing the joint distribution is multivariate Normal?

Comment: I forgot to mention that U and V should be independent.

Comment: I formatted some math symbols.  However, many statements in your post are conceptually wrong and better to be corrected by yourself.  For example, the conditional mean and variance of $X$ given $S = s$ is obviously not as you stated (please refer to the link in my answer below for the correct conditional distribution formula), and why after saying $U$ and $V$ are normal, then stating "$U$ and $V$ are uniformly distributed"???

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to correct the statements. In the last part I was trying to tell why I thought that knowing S and T is more than knowing their average only. For this explanation I simplified U and V to uniform. However, I removed it from the question because it was rather confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $X, U, V \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$ (in general the analysis below requires the joint normality of $(X, U, V)$). The joint normality of $(X, U, V)$ and transformations
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
S \\
T
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
U \\
V
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
R
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
a + b & a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
U \\
V
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
then indicate that
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
S \\
T
\end{bmatrix} \sim N_3\left(0, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\right), 
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
R
\end{bmatrix} \sim 
N_2\left(0,  
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a + b  \\
a + b & 2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2
\end{bmatrix}\right).
\end{align*}
It then follows by [the conditional distribution of multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) that
\begin{align*}
& E[X|S, T] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} S \\ T \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3}(S + T), \\
& E[X|R] = \frac{a + b}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}R = \frac{a + b}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}(aS + bT).
\end{align*}
So the equality holds if and only if
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
3a(a + b) = 2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2 \\
3b(a + b) = 2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
This equation holds for any $a, b$ such that $a = b$.

For the general $(X, U, V) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ case (the zero-mean condition is essential and cannot be relaxed), repeating the argument above yields $E[X|S, T] = AS + BT$ for some constants $A, B$ depending on $\Sigma$ (in the above i.i.d. case, $A = B = 1/3$). Now apply the argument in Yves's answer would give you at least one choice of $(a, b) := (A, B)$, because $\sigma(R) = \sigma(AS + BT) \subset \sigma(S, T)$ and the law of iterative expectations:
\begin{align*}
E[X|R] = E[E[X|S, T]|R] = E[R|R] = R = E[X|S, T]. 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

I assume that we have $U,V,X$ independent. Then...

- One may describe the observation $X,S,T$ by a multivariate normal distribution.
- We can always transform a multivariate normal distribution into another by using a linear transformation. So it should be possible to describe this with three other values

  $$\begin{array}{l}X\\
       R = aS + bT \\
       Q = cS + dT \\\end{array}$$
  and the trio $X,R,Q$ is also multivariate normal distributed and $R, Q$ carry the same information as $S, T$.
- If we choose the coefficients for $Q$ as $c = -d = 1$ such that $Q = S - T = U-V$ and $\text{Cov}(Q,X) = 0$.

  If we choose the coefficients for $R$ as $a = 1/\sigma_U^2$ and $b = 1/\sigma_V^2$ such that $\text{Cov}(Q,R) = 0$.

  then the multivariate normal distribution of X,R,Q can be factorized (in the fashion of the [Fisher-Neyman factorization
  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem)). We can rewrite the joint distribution as a product $$f(X,R,Q) = g(X,R) \cdot h(Q)$$ where $g$ and $h$ are independent distributions. This makes that $Q$ is an ancillary statistic independent of $X$ and  only $R$ will contain information and $R$ will be a sufficient statistic.

> As a heuristic, I think knowing $S$ and $T$ is more than just knowing their sum.

You know more, but not more about $X$. It is similar to the principle that the sample mean of iid normal distributed variables provides all information about the mean of the distribution.