# Calculating the parameters of a Normal distribution using alpha and beta from Inverse-gamma (conjugate prior)

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-family, hyperparameter, conjugate-prior, inverse-gamma-distribution

How is it possible to calculate the variance $\sigma^2$ for the Normal distribution if only $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (based on data) from the Inverse-gamma distribution are available? I followed the definitions on the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) and found out that for a Normal distribution in case of unknown variance and known mean the cojugate distribution is the Inverse-gamma with the updates $\alpha = \alpha + \frac{1}{2}$ and $\beta = \beta + \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2}$.

I tried $\sigma^2 = \frac{\beta^2}{(\alpha - 1)^2 (\alpha - 2)} \text{for } \alpha > 2$ but $\alpha$ becomes less than $2$ after an update, and the variance returns `NaN`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "only"? You do not have data?

Comment: Edited the question and added the fact that data is used.

Comment: But do you want to estimate variance of the distribution of $\sigma^2$, or do you want to estimate $\sigma^2$ itself?

Comment: I want to estimate $\sigma^2$ in order to calculate the Normal distribution using Conjugate families. In case of Gaussian with known mean and unknown variance the conjugate resembles the Inverse-gamma distribution with the already mentioned update rules (see original post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When estimating the variance of normal distribution with known mean $\mu$ using conjugate [inverse gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) *prior*, the model is

$$
X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2) \\
\sigma^2 \sim \mathrm{IG}(\alpha, \beta)
$$

So we assume an inverse gamma prior parametrized by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for $\sigma^2$. When we observe some data $x_1,\dots,x_n$ we can update our *prior*, to get *posterior* distribution of $\sigma^2$ and since inverse gamma is a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior), the update has a simple closed-form solution. The updated parameters become

$$
\alpha' = \alpha + \frac{n}{2}, \qquad \beta' = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{2}
$$

and the posterior distribution of $\sigma^2$ is inverse gamma parametrized by $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$. So by updating the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters you already *estimated* the distribution of $\sigma^2$. If you want to obtain a point estimate of $\sigma^2$, then you can calculate mean $\tfrac{\beta'}{\alpha'-1}$ or mode $\tfrac{\beta'}{\alpha'+1}$ of it's posterior distribution. What you were trying to do, is you were trying to calculate the variance of $\sigma^2$, that is certainly not it's point estimate.

Check also
[Bayesian updating with conjugate priors using the closed form expressions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232824/bayesian-updating-with-conjugate-priors-using-the-closed-form-expressions/232861#232861) and [Bayesian updating with new data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/bayesian-updating-with-new-data/237109#237109) for similar questions.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds plausible. Will have a more detailed look in a couple of minutes and accept your answer afterwards. Maybe I will come up with some questions if I work through the similar questions.

Comment: The mean or mode calculation of the point estimate of $\sigma^2$ both take the form $\frac{\beta'}{\alpha'-1}$, is this correct or just a typo?

Comment: @NumbThumb they differ by using + or - sign see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution