# Modeling "Pay as Much as You Want" with a Bayesian Model

Tags: bayesian, inference, hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior

I have data of sales of a certain product which is sold "Pay as Much as You Want".
The daily data is in the form of number of sales per day and the total revenue per day:

| Day | Sales | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 70.5 |
| 2 | 12 | 82.1 |
| 3 | 8 | 55.1 |
| 4 | 15 | 110.7 |
| 5 | 6 | 54.6 |
| 6 | 9 | 61.2 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |

I am after building a model of the average sale price of the product.
I want to use a Bayesian model.

I thought about a model built with Gamma Likelihood with Gamma Prior.
I thought doing so as I saw that [Gamma Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is used to model the size of insurance claims.

Reading the [Conjugate Prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) page made me lost on how properly to do so.

So my questions are:

1. Is the Gamma Likelihood with Gamma Prior a reasonable model? If not, is there a better model at all? Any better model limited to a conjugate prior form?
2. The [Wikipedia - Conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) page lists 3 different variations of the likelihood an prior. I am struggling on which one to choose an how to connect $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ to the average price. I thought maybe $ \beta $ to represent the number of sales and $ \alpha $ the total revenue, will it make sense?

Comment: Can you give us some more details? Do you have covariables? which? sample size? Show us some plots? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I added an example of the structure of the data.

Comment: There are two parameterizations of the gamma distribution in common usage. You ask for a good choice of $\alpha, \beta$, but don't tell us what these parameters mean. Can you [edit] to include the pdf of the distribution?

Comment: @Sycorax, I tried making things clearer. Let me know if it works for you now.