# Closed Form Bayesian Updating with single observations of unknown variance to estimate mean

Tags: bayesian

So here is another question regarding bayesian updating, which I try to understand.

In my scenario, I sequentially process single pieces of information from an unknown distribution.
*I am interested in estimating the mean of this distribution*.

[According to my readings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/bayesian-updating-with-new-data), best would be, to know the variance of the observed distribution. Well, it would be better, to know the mean, but I don't know either, and (appart from maybe the need for the process of bayesian updating) I am also not interested in knowing the variance.

So my questions:

1. Do I need to estimate this variance, if it is not in my desired output? What is the downside on largly over/underestimating this variance, by just stating e.g. I assume it is something 50ish?
2. If so, how would I do that, given that I process a single draw at a time.
3. Would it help, if I introduced a short-term memory holding a few (maybe 1 or 2 of the past values) to estimate the variance of the samples?

Now, [what I read was](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232824/bayesian-updating-with-conjugate-priors-using-the-closed-form-expressions/232861#232861), that I would need to estimate the variance using the *inverse gamma distribution* with two parameters $\alpha, \beta$ - which I assume I somehow need to have?
What is the intuitive undestanding of those parameters in my scenario?

Comment: As a Bayesian, one need put priors on all unknown parameters.

Comment: Just because you’re not interested in it means it’s known. In Bayesian statistics,  everything unknown, collectively, gets a prior distribution put on it before you see any data. After you see the data you get a posterior distribution. If you are only interested in one of those two parameters, then you take the joint distribution and integrate out the quantity you’re not interested in.

Comment: So basically, instead of saying it is something 50ish, I say I assume it is gamma-distributed, and choose alpha and beta, such that the mean of my gamma-distribution is 50, and then I syncronously update my gamma-distribution and my normal distribution with each observation?