# Parallel with Weighted Least Squared in Bayesian Regression

Tags: r, hierarchical-bayesian, weighted-regression, stan

I have a dataset with a column of ratios $Y = z_1 / z_2$, which will be my depending variable, and a set of columns that explain $Y$.

Here $z_1$ means "imports" and $z_2$ means "exports", which for different products comes from yearly data of the form

```
Year: 2021

Product: Portable automatic data processing machines, 
 weighing not > 10 kg, consisting of a least a central processing unit, 
 a keyboard & a display

Exporter | Importer | Value reported by the exporter | Value reported by the importer 
USA      | Canada   | 100                            | 110
```

In this data both values may contain errors, and in a perfect world the value reported by the importer should be equal to the value reported by the exporter plus cost of transport.

In addition to the columns required to fit a model involving $Y \mid (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, I have an additional column of weights $W$, that I computed as $[\min(z_1,z_2) / \max(z_1,z_2)]^2$, so that it reflects the discrepancy between the variables used for the ratio.

In this problem I am interested in giving more weight to more concordant observations.

Under a classic approach I would write

```r
glm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + ..., link = gaussian(), weights = w)
# or Gamma()
```

Is there an approach to do this in Stan? The documentation points at integer sampling/survey weights. For a bayesian model I've written the next Stan code which is *not* minimizing the sum of weighted squared residuals to produce residuals with a constant variance, but at least fits a hierarchical model.

```
data{
  int<lower=1> N; // number of observations
  vector[N] Y; // dependent variable CIF/FOB ratios
  vector[N] dist; // independent variable "distance"
  vector[N] year; // independent variable "year"
  vector[N] contig; // independent variable "contiguity"
  vector[N] colony; // independent variable "colony"
  vector[N] comlang_off; // independent variable "common language"
  vector[N] rta; // independent variable "regional trade agreement"
  vector[N] reporter_trade_sanction; // independent variable "sanctioned reporter"
  vector[N] partner_trade_sanction; // independent variable "sanctioned partner"
  int<lower=1, upper=6> reporter_continent[N]; // independent variable "reporter continent"
  int<lower=1, upper=6> partner_continent[N]; // independent variable "partner continent"
}

parameters {
  vector[8] beta;
  vector[6] alpha_reporter_continent;
  vector[6] alpha_partner_continent;
  real<lower=0> sigma_reporter_continent;
  real<lower=0> sigma_partner_continent;
  real<lower=0> sigma_mod;
}

model {
  target += normal_lpdf(Y | alpha_reporter_continent[reporter_continent] +
    alpha_partner_continent[partner_continent] +
    beta[1]*dist + beta[2]*year + beta[3]*contig +
    beta[4]*colony + beta[5]*comlang_off + beta[6]*rta +
    beta[7]*reporter_trade_sanction + beta[8]*partner_trade_sanction, sigma_mod);

  // priors
  target += normal_lpdf(alpha_reporter_continent | 0, sigma_reporter_continent);
  target += normal_lpdf(alpha_partner_continent | 0, sigma_partner_continent);
  target += normal_lpdf(beta | 0, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian log-likelihood is

$$
\log \mathcal{L}(y|\mathbf{X},\boldsymbol{\beta}) = -\sum_i \frac{(y_i - \mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^2}{\sigma^2}
$$

When you are minimizing weighted least squares, the loss function is

$$
L(y, \hat y) = \sum_i w_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2
$$

So in the Bayesian scenario, this basically means that your likelihood becomes

$$
\prod_i \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta},~\sigma^2/w_i)
$$

i.e. instead of having constant variance $\sigma^2$, it is multiplied by the inverse of the non-negative weights $w_i$ for each observation, so [more weight leads to more precision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211419/whats-in-a-name-precision-inverse-of-variance/211421#211421).