# Interpretation of "virtual observations" in Bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

In the context of using a Normal-Gamma conjugate prior, scale $\eta_0$ can be interpreted as "virtual observations" which is a multiple of variance. Why then is the higher the "virtual observations", the higher the variance of $\mu$? I would have thought more "observations" will lead to lower variance? Is "virtual observation" a misnomer?

See page 13 of [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter9.pdf) doc.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice what they say

> To simplify the algebra we will work with precisions instead of variances. ... in summary, by starting with a normal-gamma prior, we obtain a normal-gamma posterior; i.e., we have found a conjugate prior for the mean and precision of the Gaussian.

They parametrize the Gaussian by mean and [*precision*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161328/why-use-precision-instead-of-variance-in-a-prior/161329#161329) $\tau$, where the variance would be inverse of the precision. Gathering more data leads to more precision. Higher precision = lower variance, so everything is as expected.

The "virtual observations" are most easily explained using [beta-binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution), or [Dirichlet-categorical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435393/could-someone-please-give-a-concrete-example-to-illustrate-the-dirichlet-distrib/435444#435444) models, where the prior parameters can be thought as counts of "successes" observed *a priori*. With other models, this intuition may be harder to gasp.

Comment: Thanks, I've misread. I've got confused with the precision parameterisation.

Comment: @stevew it's uncommon parametrization, but you can see it sometimes in Bayesian literature because, as they say, using gamma prior for precision gives a little bit more simpler algebra that using inverse-gamma for variance.